# How to detect when a major compaction is completed in Acuumulo?

Tags: java, accumulo

I have an Iterator set at major compaction scope which I am using to write to a table. So it starts whenever I want to do a major compaction. But I want to query this table after the writing process has finished. For that I will need to know if the major compaction has completed and all the data has been written in the table or not. Is there a way or approach through which I can get to know this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you request the major compaction, you can add a flag to the command so that it only returns after the compaction is complete.  In the shell this is "compact -w".  In the Java API, set the wait parameter to true for one of the connector.tableOperations().compact(...) methods.